# Getting my application to open in Sublime text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Today I've installed Ruby on Rails onto my PC (windows 7 64x), managed to generate an application in the command prompt by entering the following:

```
rails new project

cd project

bundle install

rails server
```

All the gems installed and everything looks fine so far according to this tutorial video I'm watching but I just can't seem to open my project in Sublime Text 2 and I'm a little confused.

In the tutorial I'm currently watching as soon as he opens Sublime Text his files are there ready to go and I cant for the love of me figure out how to do it. I've tried to 'Add folder to project' under the Project tab but to no avail.

Do you think I'm selecting the wrong folder?

This is the directory of the folder I select

> C:\ruby\projects\testblog

I created the projects folder myself if that means anything..

Sorry for sounding dumb but I only started learning this morning and I'm eager to learn more but I'm stuck at the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Drag the folder of your project and drop on the Sublime Text window. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to click File->Open and select the project enclosing folder.
That will open a hierarchical view of your project.
Hope that it helps you.